# FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br /> ^ )

Tags: flutter, http

please help me.

FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

^
)

im code
`Diagnosa hasilDiagnosa = await DiagnosaService().submitDiagnosa(gejalaIds);`

and iam code home.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nadia/models/gejala.dart';
import 'package:nadia/models/diagnosa.dart';
import 'package:nadia/screens/hasil_diagnosa.dart';
import 'package:nadia/services/service_diagnosa.dart';
import 'package:nadia/services/services_gejala.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key});

  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  late Future<List<Gejala>> gejalaFuture;
  List<Gejala> selectedGejala = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    gejalaFuture = GejalaService().getGejala();
  }

  void _submitDiagnosa() async {
    // Membuat list ID gejala yang dipilih
    List<String> gejalaIds = selectedGejala.map((gejala) => gejala.id).toList();

    // Mengirim data ke API untuk proses diagnosa
    Diagnosa hasilDiagnosa = await DiagnosaService().submitDiagnosa(gejalaIds);

    // Navigasi ke halaman hasil diagnosa dengan membawa data hasil diagnosa
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HasilDiagnosaScreen(
          hasilDiagnosa: [hasilDiagnosa],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Diagnosa",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 26,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Gejala>>(
        future: gejalaFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Gagal mendapatkan gejala"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Gejala> gejalaList = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: gejalaList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Gejala gejala = gejalaList[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(gejala.nama),
                  trailing: Checkbox(
                    value: selectedGejala.contains(gejala),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (value != null && value) {
                          selectedGejala.add(gejala);
                        } else {
                          selectedGejala.remove(gejala);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Tidak ada gejala yang tersedia."),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _submitDiagnosa,
        child: Icon(Icons.check),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HasilDiagnosaScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Diagnosa> hasilDiagnosa;

  const HasilDiagnosaScreen({required this.hasilDiagnosa});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hasil Diagnosa'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: hasilDiagnosa.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Diagnosa diagnosa = hasilDiagnosa[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(diagnosa.nama),
            subtitle: Text(
                'Probabilitas: ${diagnosa.probabilitas.toStringAsFixed(2)}%'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.medical_services),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:nadia/models/diagnosa.dart';

class DiagnosaService {
  static final String _baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/api/api_diagnosa.php";

  Future<Diagnosa> submitDiagnosa(List<String> gejalaIds) async {
    Uri uriApi = Uri.parse(_baseUrl);

    final response = await http.post(
      uriApi,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode({"gejala": gejalaIds}),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Mengonversi respons JSON menjadi Map<String, dynamic>
      var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      // Mengonversi Map<String, dynamic> menjadi List<dynamic> (jika diperlukan)
      List<dynamic> dataList = responseData['data'];
      final Map<String, dynamic> firstDiagnosa =
          responseData.isNotEmpty ? responseData[0] : {};
      return Diagnosa.fromJson(firstDiagnosa);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Gagal melakukan diagnosa");
    }
  }
}
```

i hope this code fix